# Requested site does not appear to have claims enabled or the Login Url has not been set

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sharepoint, claims-based-identity, sharepoint-online

i am currently getting information from my company's sharepoint page and display it on my asp.net project. I am using *ClaimClientContext* for authentication, and of course in my local host it is working fine.

However, when I publish the site and place it on my server the following error occurred: *The requested site does not appear to have claims enabled or the Login Url has not been set.*

The error is pointing to the Url which i have stated in my code:

```
 Using ctx As ClientContext = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext("https://abc.sharepoint.com/team/Wiki/")
```

Any idea on how I can overcome this error? Do let me know if more information is needed, and i will gladly provide. Thank you.

Comment: The error message states two potential issues.  Have you checked both of those to their logical conclusion?

Comment: hi @jmcilhinney, i have tried going to https://abc.sharepoint.com/team/Wiki/, and it does an authentication before redirecting me to the actual page. Therefore, i am not sure what it meant by login url has not been set. As for requested site does not have claims enabled, must i go to the Sharepoint online page to change some settings? 
I have read, some said it is due to the app. pool setting but i have checked and same problem still exist.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. After struggling with this for quite a bit now, I was able to resolve the issue. Its something to do with oAuth2 not supporting old protocols.
You can resolve with the below power shell commands

```
Connect-SPOService  -Url https://<yourdomain>-admin.sharepoint.com -credential <adminIDwithElevatedPrivileges>
Set-SPOTenant -LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled  $True
```

You might have to wait for sometime after running this command.
Hope this helps!